# Why does the third box appear lower on the line than the others despite the same CSS?

Tags: html, css

All the boxes are exactly the same CSS. The only difference is the first two have images and the third has text. Why is it lower?

https://jsfiddle.net/1guxjmLe/3/

It even appears lower if in the middle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1guxjmLe/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
      <div class="photo">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="http://www.comune.roncade.tv.it/public/Image/servizi_uffici/casa.jpg" media="(min-width: 47.5625em)">
            <source srcset="http://www.comune.roncade.tv.it/public/Image/servizi_uffici/casa.jpg" media="(max-width: 47.5em)">
            <img srcset="http://www.comune.roncade.tv.it/public/Image/servizi_uffici/casa.jpg" alt="">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <span>
          This is
          some text
          in here
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="photo">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="http://www.comune.roncade.tv.it/public/Image/servizi_uffici/casa.jpg" media="(min-width: 47.5625em)">
            <source srcset="http://www.comune.roncade.tv.it/public/Image/servizi_uffici/casa.jpg" media="(max-width: 47.5em)">
            <img srcset="http://www.comune.roncade.tv.it/public/Image/servizi_uffici/casa.jpg" alt="">
        </picture>
      </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content
{
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: #fec321;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .photo
{
  position: relative;
  border: solid .75em #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  display: inline-block;
}

.content picture, .content img, .content .description span
{
  position: relative;
  width: 14em;
  height: 14em;
  display: block;
}

.content .description
{
  position: relative;
  border: solid .75em #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [vertical-align:top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

```
.content .description,
.content .photo {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcyspv0u/)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! Any idea why I need that? Why do parent `div`'s with child `img` elements need that?

Comment: @DonRhummy the default vertical-align of an inline or inline-block element is `baseline`, which is usually calculated(I think, might want to look this up), by the text content of the div. The `.photo` elements probably doesn't  need it, but you can still add it to be on the safe side.

Comment: but the `.photo` element is also an inline-block. So why doesn't that need it?

Comment: @DonRhummy It has no text content

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to the `.description` and `.photo` since you have defined these `<div>`s as inline-blocks.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dt0qLmd/).